# (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) .

I'm trying to connect to my online database from my vb website project but always getting the error above

i tried to change the server name to an ip,localhost but still the same problem !

my connecting string

cnn.ConnectionString = "server=mrsandg.com; user=username ;password=password ;Database=my_db;"

i checked

[Connecting to a Online MySQL Database using VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269237/connecting-to-a-online-mysql-database-using-vb-net)

[SqlConnection error Named Pipes Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209464/sqlconnection-error-named-pipes-provider)

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/488146/how-to-connect-vb-net-on-a-online-database

Comment: Please explain. Your online db is MySql or Sql Server? And where is the code that tries to open the connection?

Comment: my database is Mysql the code : cnn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection cnn.ConnectionString = "server=mrsandg.com; user=username ;password=password ;Database=my_db;"                                            Try
         cnn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        If cnn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            MsgBox("DB Connection Faild")
        End If   @Steve

Comment: If the database is MySql then you should use the classes for MySql not the ones for Sql Server. Download and install the MySql Net Connector, (or just use NuGet Package Manager), add the reference to the MySql dll and add the appropriate namespaces to your code. Finally change every SqlXXXXX class with the matching ones for MySql (MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand and so on...)

Comment: the Net Connector is already installed , but what do you mean by  "add the reference to the MySql dll " ?do you mean to add the reference on my project ? i couldn't find it :( @Steve

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a library you need to reference it. Usually with a right click on the project reference node you can add a new reference. But you can simply use the NuGet Package Manager, search for MySql.Data and install. This will download the library and add the required reference to your project. Next you need _Import MySql.Data.MySqlClient_ in the file where you want to use the MySql classes

Comment: woooorkd ! too many thanx :) @Steve

Comment: @RuaaElias Please add your comments as an answer so Steve can mark it correct and so Steve and others can up vote.

Comment: How to do that please ? @Alexander Higgins

Comment: Steve needs to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` in an attempt to connect to a `MySql` server.

To connect to `MySql` you need to use a `MySqlConnection` which will require you adding a reference MySql provider for Ado.Net called `MySql.Data`

The easiest way to do this is by using NuGet Package Manager. In Visual Studio Click: Tools > NuGet Package Manger -> Manage Nuget Packages For Solution.

In the form, click on Browse and select MySql.Data.

[image]

*Note: there is also an EntityFramework provider if you wish to use that instead of Ado.Net.*

From Here, check the projects you want to use the provider in and click install.